# How to get cross validation accuracy

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, naivebayes

I am learning dataset from this page. 
https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/classification.html

The code I have now is:

```
load iris_dataset.dat
gscatter(meas(:,1), meas(:,2), species,'rgb','osd');
xlabel('Sepal length');
ylabel('Sepal width');
N = size(meas,1);
cp = cvpartition(species,'KFold',10)
nbGau = fitcnb(meas(:,1:2), species);
nbGauResubErr = resubLoss(nbGau)
nbGauCV = crossval(nbGau, 'CVPartition',cp);
nbGauCVErr = kfoldLoss(nbGauCV)
labels = predict(nbGau, [x y]);
gscatter(x,y,labels,'grb','sod')
```

I can only get  resubstitution error and the cross-validation error, how can I get classification accuracy?

Comment: What do you mean by "classification accuracy"? Probably the (estimated) test error?

Comment: @hbaderts Yes, how much percent of test data is correct. because i use k-fold cross validation.